# Display PowerShell script's file name in Windows 7 task bar

Tags: powershell, windows-7-x64, powershell-3.0

Is there a way to get PowerShell IDE to display the name of the active script in its title bar so that it is displayed in windows task bar?  There isn't an obvious setting to do so.

By default, Windows 7 task bar displays:

[image]

It would be helpful to display the name of the active script in each IDE instance.

Comment: You can set title explicitly: `$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle=$psISE.CurrentFile.DisplayName`. Problem is to have it updated automatically.

Comment: I think this should be directed to Powershell ISE developers, so that they would update the window title if a script is open in ISE.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the WindowTitle explicitly in your script it works:

```
$host.ui.rawui.WindowTitle = "Script 42"
```

[image: renamed ISE]